# Strange facebook like box behaviour

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I have a simple yet hard problem here that is driving me nuts ...

Apparantly with no code change what so ever the facebook and Google+ like boxes show as I want in one section of my site: http://www.nfrases.com/coragem yet on the other they just disappear http://www.nfrases.com/coragem/1519

I'm going crazy over here! Someone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using the relative path

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

When the address changed the scripts.js file wasn't loading. Using:

```
<script src="http://www.nfrases.com/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

It's always loaded no matter what address the user is accessing.

It was a dumb mistake!